# Why does make.exe try to run /usr/bin/sh on Windows?

Tags: windows-10, mingw, gnu-make

I have recently moved from Window 7 to Windows 10 and I cannot get my makefiles to work anymore.

I have been using the [GNU Make for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm)

The first thing that I noticed was that it had started treating Windows folder dividers (backslash characters '\') as line continuation characters, so I modified the 'clean' section as shown below to use forward slash '/' characters instead:

```
clean:
    del $(ObjDir)/*.o
```

When I call `make -ftest.mak clean` I get the following error which suggests it is now trying to run in a MinGw/Cygwin environment:

```
c:\Test\Source>make -ftest.mak clean
del obj/*.o
/usr/bin/sh: del: command not found
make: *** [clean] Error 127
```

I do have MinGw folder on my PC (which I have renamed to stop make looking for it) and I can't see any 'MingGw' related environment variables in my Cmd.exe environment or PATH

How can I get `make` working so it doesn't try executing `sh` under Windows?

Is there some configuration parameter somewhere that makes it call `sh` instead of `cmd.exe`?

Update: Just tried running make -d which logs debug output. It looks as though it is using my Git folder as some sort of root folder:

```
Must remake target `clean'.
del obj/*.o
CreateProcess(NULL,C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/sh.exe -c "del obj/*.o",...)
Putting child 0x006e7fc0 (clean) PID 7234712 on the chain.
```

Comment: GNU Make will not employ any fallible heuristics to detect your shell if you
specify it in the makefile, like `SHELL := cmd`, as per [5.3.2 Choosing the Shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The cleanest way is to specify `SHELL` on command line.

```
make -ftest.mak clean SHELL=cmd
```

will do the job. **ndk-build** will do that for you, see your `ndk-build.cmd`. Don't try to run `ndk-build` bash script on Windows. The scripts in NDK may go amoc when you run them on Windows in bash.

Comment: Thanks - this question related to a proprietary build system rather then Android. :-)

Answer (score 7):

Nasty conclusion to this problem.

`make` looks through the `PATH` environment variable for anything containing `usr/bin`. It just so happens that since I also installed Git on my Windows 10 PC, Git added the following folder to `PATH`:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin
```

Adding **any** path with the substring "usr\bin" will cause make to try running `sh` instead of `cmd.exe` on Windows.

My solution: Remove the `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` from my `PATH`.

**Update:** I changed the name from `usr\bin` to `user\bin` but `make` still finds `sh.exe` within that folder. In the end I renamed `sh.exe` to `_sh.exe` within the `Git\usr\bin` folder.

Comment: So according to what you said, it was the presence of sh.exe in the PATH that caused make to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're `Makefile` must work on Windows and Linux, you can set the `SHELL` like this (adjust as needed, e.g. `powershell.exe` or `/bin/sh` should also work):

```
export

ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
    # Windows
    SHELL = cmd.exe
else
    # Linux
    SHELL = /bin/bash
endif

[...]
```